# Deseasonalize Data with auto.arima in R

Tags: r, stl

I am using the stl function to deseasonalize monthly data in R. The `stl` function is setup as  `info = stl(x, robust = TRUE, s.window = periodic)`.  Using the information from the `stl` function I seasonally adjust the data as `sea.adj = x - info$seasonal`.

Now my question is why after seasonally adjusting the data `auto.arima` still reflects seasonal AR and MA terms? Is the `s.window = "per"` not a viable enough option in this case?

Comment: If you spell it `s.window = periodic`, it should throw an error (*object 'periodic' not found*). Also, it should be `sea.adj = x - info$time.series[,1]`.

Comment: Why not just use `auto.arima` and check the resulting residuals for autocorrelation i your aim is to seasonally adjust the time-series?

Comment: This is correct Shekeine the main purpose is to seasonally adjust the time series.